# Show that the Vietoric sets form a basis for the hyperspace

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, we define the hyperspace of $X$ as the set of all closed subsets of $X$, some denote this set $2^X$. The topology of $X$ is defined in terms of the basis, which consists of sets of the form (called Vietoric ) $$\langle U_1,\ldots,U_n\rangle=\{A\in 2^X\mid A\subseteq \bigcup_{i\leq n} U_i\text{ and } A\cap U_i\neq \emptyset \text{ for } i\leq n\} $$
I want to show that this collection of Vietoric sets form indeed a basis. They clearly cover $X$, the only thing left to be shown is that for any $C$ belonging to the intersection of two Vietoric sets $U=\langle U_1,\ldots, U_n \rangle$ and $V=\langle V_1,\ldots , V_m \rangle $ there is another Vietoric $W=\langle W_1,\ldots ,W_r \rangle $ such that $C\in W\subset U\cap V $. How could I go into proving this?

Comment: It was meant be $A\cap U_i\neq \emptyset$, sorry. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: You also forgot to mention that each $U_i$ is open in $X$. The proof of this is given in this [paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1951-071-01/S0002-9947-1951-0042109-4/home.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\mathcal{U}=\bigcup_{i\leq n}U_i$ and $\mathcal{V}=\bigcup_{j\leq m}V_j$, then $\langle U_1\cap \mathcal{V},\ldots , U_n\cap \mathcal{V},V_1\cap \mathcal{U},\ldots, V_m\cap \mathcal{U} \rangle $ is the Vietoric you are looking for.